# .net core 7 mvc web app hosted on IIS 10 inprocess - when using GetServerVariable always null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I have an MVC web application that was upgraded from .net framework 4.7.1 to core version 7.  The web server (IIS 10) sits behind a load balancer and a single sign on service and the app is being run in process.

The single sign on service sets a server variable that I need access to.

Using HttpContext.GetServerVariable and its underlying context.Features.Get(), the server variables are always null.

Has anyone had success with .net core 7 / IIS in retrieving server variables ?

Comment: .NET Framework and .NET Core are completely different runtimes and there's no expectation that web apps run under IIS. How did you [publish the web app to IIS?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)? How does it run? [In-process or out-of-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-7.0)? If the app runs out of process it won't have access to IIS at all.

Comment: thanks, the application is running in process and everything is working in .Net Core 7 except for retrieval of server variables.  I mentioned the .Net framework version to highlight that the server variables are available in IIS.

Comment: Why do you want this? Most likely there are other ways to do what you want. ASP.NET Core applications can run standalone, behind reverse proxies or hosted under NGINX or IIS. They can't depend on server variables for most important information, certainly not request information

Comment: As for the method itself, [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f136052490cdf7f06dedc6868a246d27f6e43856/src/Http/Http.Extensions/src/HttpContextServerVariableExtensions.cs#L22) (and the docs) show it will return `null` if the variable isn't available or if the `IServerVariablesFeature` isn't enabled. Try calling to `context.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();` to see if it is.

Comment: need a single sign on server variable, have you been successful in retrieving sever variables using .net core ?

Comment: I have tried the underlying Features.Get with the same result

Comment: Server variables have nothing at all to do with SSO. Again, what are you trying to do? What do you mean SSO? All the authentication mechanisms in ASP.NET Core work without requiring an external hosting server. Whether you want Windows, Azure AD, Google, Facebook, Open ID, whatever, all work through middleware in the web app itself. Adding one or more of them is documented

Comment: In fact, when you create a new web app either in VS or in the command line you have the option to specify what kind of authentication you want

Comment: Perhaps you should check the [Authentication docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)? There are articles for [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), [Facebook, Google, Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) accounts, [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: our dns routes through sso and load balancing, the sso sets a server variable that I need access to in my app.

Comment: I don't have an authentication issue, my issue is .net core under iis, in process, does not have access to server variables.

Comment: How is that variable set? From a header? You can check the request headers directly

Comment: thanks, it is retrievable from the  Request Header, I will use it from there, how do I mark your answer as correct?